# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Why does $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x} = 0$? I tried L`Hospital Rule, epsilon-delta definition of a limit, but none works.

Comment: Taylor series work the best in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these ones it is simplest to sub $u=1/x$. Then $x\rightarrow 0^+$ is the same as $u\rightarrow\infty$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}
=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}ue^{-u^2}
=\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}\frac u{e^{u^2}}=0
 $$
by L'Hospital's rule. The limit as $x\rightarrow0^-$ is zero by the same method. It's a common trick when you have a lot of $1/x$'s that you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x}=u \implies u=\frac{1}{x}\\x \to  0 \space \text{then}  \space  u \to \infty $$
$$\large \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}}{x}=
\large \lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{e^{-u^2}}{\frac{1}{u}}=
\large \lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{u}{e^{+u^2}}\\
\large \lim_{u \to \infty}\frac{u}{1+u^2+\frac{u^4}{2!}+\frac{u^6}{3!}+...} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=x^{-1}$ we get
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}}{x}=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }\frac{t}{e^{t^{2}}}\rightarrow 0$$